# Assembly - Convert value to ascii

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, ascii, system-calls

I found here some topics about converting value to ascii. But I am a bit stuck here.
Here's my code:

```
    ;GetPID

SECTION .data

msg:    db "Your PID is:"       ;pidmsg
msgl:   equ $-msg           ;pidlen

lookup: db "0123456789"

SECTION .bss

pid:    resb 8              ;test is a variable im testing to
                        ;receive the eax from sys_getpid

SECTION .text
        global _start

_start:
        call getpid          ;get pid number into eax
        mov ebx,0xa
        lea ebp, [pid+6]
        call ASCIIC
        jmp exit             ;exit
exit:
        mov eax,1
        mov ebx,0
        int 0x80
getpid:
        mov eax,20          ;getpid function (sys_getpid)
        int 0x80
        ret
            ;ASCIIC was taken from http://theropfather.github.io/asm/getpid_tutorial.html
ASCIIC:
        div ebx                            ;Divide the PID
        mov byte cl, [lookup+edx]      ;Copy ASCII value to CL
        mov [ebp], cl                      ;Copy ASCII value to buffer
        dec ebp                            ;Next byte into buffer
        xor edx, edx                       ;Clear the remainder
        inc eax                            ;Dec eax tricking jnz
        dec eax                            ;Push back to original value
        jnz ASCIIC                         ;Keep looping until eax is zero
        call .printPID                     ;Print out the buffer
        ret

.printPID:
    mov ecx, msg                    ;message
    mov edx, msgl                   ;msg len
    mov ebx,0x1                     ;FD stdout
    mov eax, 0x4                    ;sys_write call
    int 0x80                            ;Call
    mov [pid+7], byte 0xA           ;Push a newline to PID string
    mov edx,0x8                     ;Max length of 8 bytes
    mov ecx,pid                     ;Push PID value
    mov ebx,0x1                     ;FD stdout
    mov eax, 0x4                    ;sys_write call
    ret
```

So the point here is get the pid number of the current program (this) and print it.
The program calls sys_getpid (eax=20) and the pidnumber is returned. But, sys_write parameters is: `ssize_t sys_write(unsigned int fd, const char * buf, size_t count)`
second argument is a char so I need to convert into char for each number.

output is only: "Your PID is:"

Anyone ? :)

Comment: Do you have to do that without using a C standard library? If not, using `printf` with a format specifier would be a lot easier than `sys_write` with fd 1.

Comment: I don't wanna use C lib. Just interrupts and system calls. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You forgot to `int 0x80` a second time to actually print the number.
- When you `div ebx`, what is calculated is `eax = edx:eax / ebx`, so you have to make sure that `edx` is zero in your case. So `xor edx,edx` before you `div ebx`.
- You should pad the front of your buffer with spaces, otherwise you might run into trouble depending on where stdout goes in the end.
- I am very suspicious about your use of `ebp` to hold the pointer to the current buffer position. While it works here, the base pointer is a special purpose register and I see no reason to abuse it here.

Comment: Also, printing zero bytes is not nice, but it may happen to work for a terminal.

Comment: @Jester Good point, thank you! I added this and another point.

Comment: yup, forgot something basic: on .printPID i forgot to do interrupt 0x80. :) thanks :P